# Running a program through Gnome GUI shell causes bad GPU behaviour, using the same command in CLI doesn't

Tags: gnome, gpu, .desktop

If I run Blender by clicking on the icon in the Gnome Launcher I get garbled GPU rubbish. If I execute the command in a terminal window it runs fine. How can I fix it so it runs without having to open up the CLI.

Blender was installed via flatpak on Mint, and the .desktop file has the command

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=blender --file-forwarding org.blender.Blender @@ %f @@
```

If I click on the icon in the Gnome Launcher I get this:
[image]

But if I execute that in the terminal using the same command (without the @@ %f @@ parameter(?)) it runs just fine:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=blender --file-forwarding org.blender.Blender
```

This is Mint 21.3, Kernel 5.15.0, Gnome 42.9 / Mutter / X11 on Nvidia GPUs with driver 535.154.05

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the command in the .desktop file?

Comment: Yep, I removed the `@@ %f @@` and tried all the combinations of parameters, even just `flatpak run org.blender.Blender` didn't work.